# Cron on EC2 only run when I am logged on?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cron, aws-cloud9

I have 2 python scripts setup on EC2 instance on cloud9 ide, script is to extract data daily from google API - but that's not relevant here I think (this is just provide some context).

So I setup (crontab-e) on my EC2 instance to let it run daily as follow :

- `15 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/environment/GAM/custom_targeting.py`
- `45 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/environment/GAM/ad_line_item_delta.py`

**Issue**:
tested multiple times, the cron job **will run only** when I am logged on to my aws. When i am log out of AWS account / or switch off my computer : the cron job doesn't run

What i tried: Removed the default 30 minutes EC2 auto hibernate feature. Currently it is set to NEVER hibernate the instance.

What I expect to happen: Cron job should start even when I am not logged in

What's the result: same issue as describe above.

I am thinking this might be an ec2 issue and not my crontab setup. Looking to see if anyone has any insights.

Edit(added what i have tried)
here are my output for respective command :
`crontab -l`

- 15 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3
  /home/ec2-user/environment/GAM/custom_targeting.py
- 45 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3
  /home/ec2-user/environment/GAM/ad_line_item_delta.py

`sudo service cron status` :

- Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status cron.service Unit cron.service
  could not be found.

`cat /etc/crontab` :

- SHELL=/bin/bashPATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin MAILTO=root

Comment: What is the output of `crontab -l` when you login? What is the output of `sudo service cron status` and `cat /etc/crontab`? The user that the cron job is registered for, may be key here which is what the last `cat ...` command will help show 

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary,
here are my output for respective command 

`crontab -l` : 
- `15 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/environment/GAM/custom_targeting.py`
- `45 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/environment/GAM/ad_line_item_delta.py`

`sudo service cron status` : 
`Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status cron.service
Unit cron.service could not be found.`

`cat /etc/crontab` : 
`SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root`

could you let me know what am i missing here, thanks heap!

Comment: Can you please add them to the question? Thank yoiu!

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks for the suggestion, was figuring out how to format the comment above. Added my findings in questions.